# After removing breakpoint in Visual Web Developer Express 2010, it keeps coming back

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

Like a zombie. I delete it by clicking on it, I remove it by right clicking on it. It keeps coming back. I close the file, I restart the VWDE process, I reboot. Doesn't matter, it's there forever. I can't see any way of getting rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility here is that Visual Studio is failing to save the deleted breakpoint to disk.  Hence it lasts for the session but comes back when you restart Visual Studio.

To test this check to see if the .suo file for your solution is readonly on disk.  Or simply delete it and restart Visual Studio and see if the problem comes back.  The .suo file is hidden but should be in the same folder as the .sln file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the menu command, Debug - Delete All Breakpoints.